# How to let Powerpoint SaveAs WMV with high priority in a Powerpoint Add-in?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

My task is to get movie frames after Save current powerpoint as WMV. The following code works fine as a standalone application but it got stuck with endless loop as "CreateVideoStatus" is always "PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusQueued" when it runs as a Powerpoint Add-in. My guess is because the SaveAs WMV operation is time-consuming so OS lowered its priority till the CPU is released by the Add-in itself. 
Would anyone please help me out? Thanks in advance.

```
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        var app = this.Application;
        var pres = app.Presentations;
        var file = pres.Open("F:\\Src\\Culturelization\\animation2.pptx");
        file.SaveAs("F:\\Src\\Culturelization\\SimpleDemo\\simple.wmv", PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV, Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
        Boolean isExporting = true;
        do
        {

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (file.CreateVideoStatus == Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusFailed && file.CreateVideoStatus == Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusDone)
            {
                isExporting = false;
            }

        } while (isExporting);                

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a new thread to check "powerpoint save as wmv" status. 
   Such as: BackgroundWorker, to avoid your main program hold on.
2. In your loop condition has a logic bug:

   ```
   if ( file.CreateVideoStatus == ppMediaTaskStatusFailed && file.CreateVideoStatus == ppMediaTaskStatusDone )
   ```

   "CreateVideoStatus" just has one status at a time. 
   Use "||" (or) not "&&" (and).

Code for reference:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace AddInName
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private BackgroundWorker checkSave_backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            checkSave_backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(checkSave_backgroundWorker_DoWork);
        }

        // ...

        private void DoSave()
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.SaveAs( saveAsWmvFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue );
            checkSave_backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }


        private void checkSave_backgroundWorker_DoWork( object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e )
        {
            bool isDone = false;
            do
            {
                Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
                if ( Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.CreateVideoStatus == Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusDone
                    || Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.CreateVideoStatus == Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusFailed
                    || Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.CreateVideoStatus == Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusNone )
                {
                    isDone = true;
                }
            } while ( !isDone );

            // Finish!
        }
    }
}
```